# UV-vis spectra - maximum absorption

Tags: uv-vis-spectroscopy

If I have a noisy UV-vis absorption band, how do I determine the maximum absorption?  Do I look for the highest absorbance value or do I look for the most intense band and take the value from the center of the band?  The second option seems correct to me, but I don't know if those noisy portions that are not in the center of the band actually represent the maximum absorption

Comment: Do you use a dispersive instrument, or not? Is the recording of the data sequential with adjustable integration time (so and so nm/s), or all at once with a CCD array? An old rule of thumb is to record $\epsilon_\text{max} = 10^n$ at concentrations no higher than $c \approx 10^{-n}$mol/L for a 10mm cell (adjustable parameters of the sample) to stay in the linear response of the detectors. Slit width, integration time (or scan rate, nm/s), and repeating the measurements (as noise signal is random, systematic signal is not) may help on side of instrumentation/software.

Comment: You can attempt to fit the peak or part of it. That will implicitly average over the noise.

Comment: I tried to fit, but it didn't help much. The recording regime is a stopped-flow one, with a dead time of 2 ms.  I just want to know how I should evaluate the maximum

Comment: "I tried to fit, but it didn't help much. " How about showing a plot, or some sample data? How is the dead time relevant, or regime? Is your point that you can't perform averaging? Perhaps it would be more relevant to describe the UV-Vis instrument.

Comment: Do you care to monitor shifts in the spectrum maximum? Or do you merely want to maximize s/n?

Comment: Yes, I want to monitor shifts in the spectrum maximum.

Comment: Ok, I still recommend providing more info as to why a fit of some sort hasn't worked. You are left with few other options if you want to work with the data you already have (otherwise look at what Buttonwood wrote and refer to the user's manual). There is no real way to avoid noise other than filtering (which if done after the fact is equivalent to a fit). Think of noise as lack of information (or useless information).

Comment: " do I look for the most intense band and take the value from the center of the band" This is equivalent to a fit. You are making assumptions about the shape of the band. The absolutely most intense point might be due to addition of noise above the signal. If you want to report the magnitude of the signal, you'll want  to provide an estimate of noise which again involves an explicit or implicit model or fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a noisy UV-VIS spectrum, one cannot pick the highest value in the spectrum because each point is "contaminated" with noise. I am assuming you are not measuring very large absorbance values. Since you have not shown the data, the easiest way is to do smoothing with a Savitsky-Golay filter. Wikipedia has a good explanation and it can be easily done in MATLAB. The nice thing here is that your UV signals are broad (low frequency signals) and noise is high-frequency, so, smoothing is not going to hurt the width of UV-peaks.

If you can have a look at the Fourier spectrum of your UV spectrum, you can see the nature of your noise in the stopped flow experiment. And as has been commented above, increasing slit width might help to reduce noise.

Comment: The relevant theory as well as implementations (typically Matlab, Octave, Python/Spider; spread sheet Microsoft Excel and OpenOffice Calc) ready to use can be found for instance in the superb resource *A Pragmatic Introduction to Signal Processing* by Tom O'Haver (University of Maryland), [link](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/TOC.html).  Did I say his project is open access?

Comment: Excellent reference by Tom. Someone was selling the book at an expensive rate on Amazon. The pdf of the book is free. I have published with the author.

Comment: Thank you so much!